# opencart seo url not redirecting mistyped product page to 404 error page

Tags: opencart

My website is on opencart, and my product page url is:

> domain.com/lace-pencil-skirt-white

but when i put any garbage value before product name like this:

> domain.com/aaasssa/lace-pencil-skirt-white

or even after product name

> domain.com/lace-pencil-skirt-white/aaaaasssa

is still opening the same page.

why this happens?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known bug and has been in the cart for a very long time. It happens because open cart goes through all of the keywords between the `/` one at a time, and if it finds one it doesn't know, it simply skips it. If it recognises one, it assumes that's the page you want. It's kind of stupid really, but you could have

```
http://yoursite.com/product-slug/category-slug/information-slug
```

and it would be the information page you see

Comment: i gei it! but what is the solution to it and how i can make it work in my system?

Comment: @Abeer Unfortunately, the solution is not that easy at all. If it were, it would be already fixed long long time ago. You can try to remove such behavior but then say *Bye-Bye* to the OpenCart's SEO itself as well...

Comment: any recommended extension/module for this?